# UITableView with 500 items in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data, xamarin.ios

I'm wondering what's the best way to handle a large list of data in a UITableView using MonoTouch and sqlite-net?  I use the MonoTouch.Dialog system but it seems that most MonoTouch devs are loading the collection then building the UITableView instead of on demand type loading as cells come into view.  I've seen apps like twitter, and others that display images and content as you scroll, contacts, etc. and want to learn the right way to do this for a great performing app.  Currently my app holds a small amount of data so I load a collection up front but I need to rework this.

Anyone have any suggestions or samples using MonoTouch to manage a UITableView with a long list of rows that can load on demand?  I think something like this is handle with CoreData for XCode devs, how are MonoTouch devs handling this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: How big are the items?  If they are small, putting them all into an IList<> shouldn't be a big concern.  If you properly cache your cells in GetCell(), the UITableView should only allocate enough cells as it needs at any one time.

Comment: Each row returned only has about 6-10 columns, nothing large. This list could grow to thousands so I'd like to know that equivalent option is for on demand loading like CoreData I believe would provide.  I haven't seen anyone really use CoreData in MonoTouch or if it's necessary.  I was thinking along the line of getting a record count of the result set then keep track of the row number and on demand query based on the row becoming visible.  It would be a lot of queries vs. one up front, just looking for the best practice such as in a Contacts application.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple suggestion. Maybe it could not fit your specification but I'll write it anyway. Maybe it could be useful.

Few months ago I was developing an iPad application with MT and I had a similar problem: retrieving a lot of items from a SQLite DB and presenting items in a `UITableView`. Since was incovenient to load data once, I followed this approach. Load in the model a bunch of data (say 50 items). Once loaded, the model is used to present data on the table. When the user reach the end of the table, I show a "Show more" label in the footer section for that table view. Then if the user click on it, load again data (other 50 items) and reload the table, and so on.

**Note** My specification was to have only one section and multiple items.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is a good suggestion, I have seen apps do that.  Kind of like "paging" but using a "Load more" metaphor.  Good suggestion.

Comment: Hope it helps. Maybe upvote the answer if you want... :-)

Comment: You guys may find a library that I wrote useful, and removes the need for having to show a "Load More" item: https://github.com/jstedfast/MonoTouch.SQLite

Answer (score 0):

I've written a simple-to-use library that takes care of a lot of the logic of incrementally loading data from SQLite into a UITableView called MonoTouch.SQLite. You can find my GitHub project here: https://github.com/jstedfast/MonoTouch.SQLite

The main class to look at is the MonoTouch.SQLite.SQLiteTableViewController class which also integrates searching support. I think you'll find that it makes displaying data from a sqlite table extremely trivial.

Feel free to fork and modify it in any way you want!